# UICollectionViewFlowlayout behave odd

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have an AS collection node, to my collectionFlowLayout object I gave:

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8;
```

When I need to show the header and when there's  only one item in the collection node, that only item becomes center aligned, if no header or more than one items: it's ok.
What can be the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: What? Also post some code

Comment: I use AsyncDisplayKit. I created HeaderNode class, which is a subclass from AsDisplayNode. And also created ImageNode, so when I have one HeaderNode & one ImageNode, my ImageNode stands in center.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not setup itemSize:

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```